# What is quiver of Quivers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

I made a triangular-shaped quiver q (with three vertices and three arrows) and gave representations to the quiver, that is these representations are objects of $Vect^{Free(q)}$. now I was trying to enumerate these objects(that is representation) with a functor $K:P \to Vect^{Free(q)}$ where P is a poset. Could I consider this functor a quiver again or maybe a representation of a quiver? Please tell me in an easy way since I am very new to representation theory.